# Is there a way to hide the mesh outlines/vertices highlights when weight painting with a mask?

Tags: weight-painting, masking

I'm weighting a dense mesh and using a mask to limit the blend tool to a certain area (a workaround for not being able to limit the blur to to visible mesh).  But when painting with a mask the active face outlines obscure the temperature gradients.  Is there any way to hide the outlines?  Alternatively, is there a way to limit the blur tool to visible vertices yet?

[image]